# SwiftUI Picker in Form does not show checkmark

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a Picker embedded in Form, however I can't get it working that it shows a checkmark and the selected value in the form.

```
NavigationView {
    Form {
        Section {
                Picker(selection: $currencyCode, label: Text("Currency")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< codes.count) {
                        Text(self.codes[$0]).tag($0)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[image: No checkmark and no selected value]

Comment: What is the initial value of `currencyCode`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Your variable `currencyCode` does not match the type of the ID for each element in your `ForEach`. Either iterate over the codes in your `ForEach`, or pass your `Picker` an index.

Below are three equivalent examples. Notice that the `@State` variable which is passed to `Picker` always matches the ID of element that the `ForEach` iterates over:

Also note that I have picked a default value for the `@State` variable which is not in the array ("", -1, UUID()), so nothing is shown when the form loads. If you want a default option, just make that the default value for your `@State` variable.

**Example 1: Iterate over codes (i.e. String)**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currencyCode: String = ""
    var codes: [String] = ["EUR", "GBP", "USD"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $currencyCode, label: Text("Currency")) {
                        // ID is a String ----v
                        ForEach(codes, id: \.self) { (string: String) in
                            Text(string)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2: Iterate over indices (i.e. Int)**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = -1
    var codes: [String] = ["EUR", "GBP", "USD"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedIndex, label: Text("Currency")) {
                        // ID is an Int --------------v
                        ForEach(codes.indices, id: \.self) { (index: Int) in
                            Text(self.codes[index])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 3: Iterate over an identifiable struct by its ID type (i.e. UUID)**

```
struct Code: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: String

    init(_ value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedUUID = UUID()
    var codes = [Code("EUR"), Code("GBP"), Code("USD")]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedUUID, label: Text("Currency")) {
                        // ID is a UUID, because Code conforms to Identifiable
                        ForEach(self.codes) { (code: Code) in
                            Text(code.value)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @gpichler: Did this work for you? I just tested all 3 examples above, and none gave me a checkmark.

Comment: @GeoffHom If you're on XCode 11.1 / iOS 13.1.2, `Picker` is broken by a bug. It's fixed in the XCode 11.2 / iOS 13.2 betas.

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to say, what you are doing wrong, because your example doesn't include the declaration of `codes` or `currencyCode`. I suspect that the problem is with the binding being of a different type than the tag you are setting on a picker (which is an Int in your case).

Anyway, this works:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let codes = Array(CurrencyCode.allCases)

    @State private var currencyCode: CurrencyCode?


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("Currency",
                           selection: $currencyCode) {
                            ForEach(codes, id: \.rawValue) {
                                Text($0.rawValue).tag(Optional<CurrencyCode>.some($0))
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


enum CurrencyCode: String, CaseIterable {

    case eur = "EUR"
    case gbp = "GBP"
    case usd = "USD"
}
```