# Why is my picker unresponsive in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker, navigationview, swiftui-picker

I've tried switching between a segmented and wheel picker, but neither register a selection when clicked.

```
NavigationView {
    Form {
        Picker(selection: self.$settings.senatorChoice, label: Text("Choose a senator")) {
            ForEach(0 ..< self.customSenators.count) {
                Text(self.customSenators[$0])
            }
        }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
        .labelsHidden()
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that `settings.senatorChoice` is an `Int`. The type of your range in `ForEach` must match the type of your `Picker`'s binding. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58104567/3088606) for more info).

In addition, you probably want to use `ForEach(self.customSenators.indices, id: \.self)`. This prevents possible crashes and out-of-date UI if elements get added to or removed from `customSenators`. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58508378/3088606) for more info.)

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to each picker item so they are unique e.g.

```swift
Text(self.customSenators[$0]).tag($0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following test code registers the selection when clicked.

```
struct Settings {
   var senatorChoice: Int = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var settings = Settings()
@State private var customSenators = ["One","Two","Three"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Picker(selection: self.$settings.senatorChoice, label: Text("Choose a senator")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< customSenators.count) {
                    Text(self.customSenators[$0])
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .labelsHidden()
                .padding()
            Text("value: \(customSenators[settings.senatorChoice])")
        }
    }
}
}
```